# Automatically generate multiple image sizes for <picture> element

Tags: images, custom-header, header-image

Suppose i want to implement a responsive header with compliance for multiple devices. To do so (with a beautiful result ofc), i need different versions of the picture, resized and cropped by their sides, then put all of them in a ... block.
I could just upload multiple versions of it, but that wouldn't be user friendly, since i'm forced to create the pictures one by one.

I thought something like adding

```
add_image_size("grand_neo", 320, 450, true);
```

to functions.php, then in my header.php get it with

```
wp_get_attachment_image($id, 'grand-neo');
```

where $id is the header image's one. But how to get it?
Thanks anyone willing to help.

Comment: A clarificatino before trying to really answer: out of box WordPress images comes with [srcset](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_srcset.asp) attribute support since [Version 4.4](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/). It automatically add some images variations for responsiveness and it allows you to filter it's values. Isn't working for you?

Comment: Function header_image returns the image's path, meaning that my <img> tag is hardcoded and includes this function as src tag. Unless i can find a way to render it as out of the box image, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar need in some projects of mine and solved by getting the image ID from it's URL and then writing the markup with [`wp_get_attachment_image`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) as it will return a markup with srcset attribute.

To get the image ID, I am using Gustavo Bordoni's helpers as it follows and shown in [here](http://bordoni.me/get-attachment-id-by-image-url/).

```
function attachment_url_to_postid( $url ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $path = $url;

    if ( 0 === strpos( $path, $dir['baseurl'] . '/' ) ) {
        $path = substr( $path, strlen( $dir['baseurl'] . '/' ) );
    }

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND meta_value = %s",
        $path
    );
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
    if ( ! empty( $post_id ) ) {
        return (int) $post_id;
    }
}
```

function attachment_url_to_postid( $url ) {
    global $wpdb;

```
$dir = wp_upload_dir();
$path = $url;

if ( 0 === strpos( $path, $dir['baseurl'] . '/' ) ) {
    $path = substr( $path, strlen( $dir['baseurl'] . '/' ) );
}

$sql = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' AND meta_value = %s",
    $path
);
$post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
if ( ! empty( $post_id ) ) {
    return (int) $post_id;
}
```

}

and it's wrapper:

```
function get_attachment_id_by_url( $url ) {
    $post_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $url );

    if ( ! $post_id ){
        $dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $path = $url;
        if ( 0 === strpos( $path, $dir['baseurl'] . '/' ) ) {
            $path = substr( $path, strlen( $dir['baseurl'] . '/' ) );
        }

        if ( preg_match( '/^(.*)(\-\d*x\d*)(\.\w{1,})/i', $path, $matches ) ){
            $url = $dir['baseurl'] . '/' . $matches[1] . $matches[3];
            $post_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $url );
        }
    }

    return (int) $post_id;
}
```

and then, the markup:

`wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, $args['desired_image_size_as_registered'] );`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try your solution. Anyways i found a way to do exactly what i was thinking about, plus avoiding to save an image for every size. I put it in [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/266979/pass-query-string-to-page/266980?noredirect=1#comment395870_266980)