# Pass query string to page

Tags: query-string

I wrote this function in my functions.php

```
function header_resized_img ($path, $width, $height) {
    $image = wp_get_image_editor($path);
    if (!is_wp_error($image)) {
        $image->resize(9999, $height, false);
        $orig_size = $image->get_size();
        $image->crop($orig_size['width']/2-$width/2, $orig_size['height']/2-$height/2, $width, $height);
        $image->stream( $mime_type = 'image/jpeg');
    }
}
```

To make it work, i created a file named page-image.php, then a page with permalink http://www.example.com/image/.
Inside page-image.php i've put (just a test)

```
header_resized_img (get_header_image(), 414, 700);
```

which, in facts, does output the resized/cropped image when i visit it. Now i want to make it more flexible and pass parameters through URL. I tried query strings using `$_GET`, then i found `get_query_arg`, but none of these seems to do the trick. How could i do this? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE. Can you please make an example of what you want to do?

Comment: Sure. If i visit the url like http://www.example.com/image/?w=360&h=480&img_path=imgpath it should execute my function on the image in imgpath, resizing and cropping it. Page should just output the image so i can embed it

Comment: @JackJohansson Doing this cause i need multiple versions of the same image

Comment: I posted an answer, see if it works. If not, check your log and see if there's some useful info in it.

Comment: I deleted the answer temporarily to figure out a way to solve your problem. Will be back shortly.

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime i'm trying to declare $_GET vars in functions.php as global

Comment: @JackJohansson Update: i tried to echo query string params. Only the first gets echoed, otherwise it prompts me the 404.

Comment: You there? You can stop working for me. Instead of use width and height as $_GET params, i put there w and h. Oddly, when i changed to width and height as you did, it worked. I suppose you can just write your previous answer back so i can accept it.

Comment: I assume it was a conflict with the WordPress's build-in queries, the same thing which happens if you use a query like `post`. Anyway, if you needed further assistance, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should actually work for you:

```
function header_resized_img () {
    $image = wp_get_image_editor($_GET['path']);
    $height = $_GET['height'];
    $width =  $_GET['width'];
    if (!is_wp_error($image)) {
        $image->resize(9999, $height, false);
        $orig_size = $image->get_size();
        $image->crop($orig_size['width']/2-$width/2, $orig_size['height']/2-$height/2, $width, $height);
        $image->stream( $mime_type = 'image/jpeg');
    }
}
```

and include your function somewhere in the template:

`header_resized_img();`

Then try accessing this URL:

`http://example.com/image/?width=500&height=400&path=some-url`

To generate your image.

Comment: It opens the 404 template

Comment: @DanieleSqualo Sorry my bad, i forgot a slash in the URL. Check out the new URL.

Comment: Same thing, a 404 page

Comment: replace the url with this : `http://example.com/index.php?page_id=YOUR_PAGE_ID&width=500&height=400&path=some-url`. If it works, let me know to write a rewrite rule for your page.

Comment: Again, the 404 page :/

Comment: Thank you. A last question. Although i'm not echoing user vars, i suppose there may be a security risk since i'm using a direct path to the image there. As far as i can see it just allows any image to be processed, anywhere on the internet. Should i sanitize it somehow?

Comment: You are welcome. That is for sure. Do you want to allow any image to be used here? If you explain to me who should be able to use it, where the images are grabbed from, and ... I can write a sanitation function for you.

Comment: I don't know if it leaves space to some abuse. Still, i tried to use something different from an image (downloadable exe, web pages, etc), tried to think how could it be exploited to generate malicious scripts, but it either outputs images or blank.
Anyways, i will either try to accept only url from the same site or even switch to attachment ID. Great help off you, thanks.

Comment: Exactly. That attachment ID was something i wanted to mention, Since it can't be abused. You can get an ID from the user and sanitized it using `filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)` to make sure it's an integer.